# why send function return 0 in socket, but clients do have recieve the message?

Tags: c++, sockets

```
void SendStr(int connfd, std::string str)
{
    uint16_t *len = new uint16_t(str.size());
    const char * lenByte = (char *)len;
    char *sendByte = new char[*len + 2]{0};
    memcpy(sendByte,lenByte,sizeof(*len));
    memcpy(sendByte + 2, str.c_str(), *len);
    std::cout << "str size " << *len << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "len size " << sizeof(len) << std::endl;

    size_t nleft = *len + 2;
    std::cout << "need to send " << nleft << std::endl;
    int nsend = 0;
    while (nleft > 0)
    {
        //std::cout << "sending " << nleft << "bytes" << std::endl;
        if (nsend = (write(connfd, sendByte + nsend, nleft)) < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            ERROR_EXIT("send");
        }
        else if (nsend == 0)
            //continue;
            break;
        nleft -= nsend;
        std::cout << "sended " << nsend << " left " << nleft << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "send complete" << std::endl;
    delete[] sendByte;
    delete len;
}
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/h53/mine-tank-cpp/blob/6f4b3deb00b4c3913357c819699002e513739f11/src/server.cpp#L181)
I see write and send function return the sum of bytes, while here returns 0, and client seems run normally, it confuses me.

Comment: FYI, you are programming in C++ and not C.  The C language does not support `delete[]` and `std::string` and `operator new`.  Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: sure, edited. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note: Writing to a socket typically means at least some of the data could be written to the socket's output buffer. It doesn't mean that data made it out onto a wire or ever got to the other side. n the case of TCP, the network stack will keep trying to send the data until it no longer can. Usually you notice data has not been sent when you've filled up the buffer and get an error message from the write to the socket or block when closing the socket, and figuring out what was or was not sent can get tricky.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the information, it really helps me a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is wrong.

In this statement

```
        if (nsend = (write(connfd, sendByte + nsend, nleft)) < 0)
```

The comparision result of `(write(connfd, sendByte + nsend, nleft)) < 0` is assingned to `nsend`. This will become `1` if the condition is true and `0` if the condition is false. It seems you are misunderstanding this comparision result as the sum of bytes.

If you want to assign what is returned from `write` to `nsend` and then compare, it should be like this:

```
        if ((nsend = write(connfd, sendByte + nsend, nleft)) < 0)
```

Addendum: The only way for `write` to return 0 on a socket is if `nleft` is 0.

Comment: Yes, I didn't check parenthese, it is a classic question. Thanks for your help!